# Undefined reference to CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned int)

Tags: c++, undefined-reference, crypto++

I am using crypto++ in c++ linux.
Here is my simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

#include "crypto++/cryptlib.h"
#include "crypto++/modes.h"
#include "crypto++/filters.h"
#include "crypto++/aes.h"
#include "crypto++/osrng.h"
#include "crypto++/strciphr.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

ifstream::pos_type size;
char * memblock;
int length;
char * _iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
char * keys[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];


void encriptCTR(byte * outbyte, const byte * inbyte, const byte * key, const byte * iv);

void encriptCTR(byte * outbyte, const byte * inbyte, const byte * key, const byte * iv)
{
    size_t inbyte_len = strlen((const char *)inbyte);
    CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption ctr_encription(key, strlen((const char*)key), iv);
    ctr_encription.ProcessData(outbyte, inbyte, inbyte_len);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open("testaja", ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg (0, ios::end);
        length = file.tellg();
        memblock = new char [length];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, length);


        if (!file)
        {
            int a;
            a = (int)file.gcount();
            file.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            file.close();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
            {
                cout << hex << (int)memblock[i] << " ";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When I run it , some error occured:

```
 undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
 undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
 undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(unsigned int)'
 undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedDeallocate(unsigned int)'
```

Then, I used command

```
gcc -o test test.cpp -L/usr/lib/crypto++ -lcrypto++
```

but this error still there :

```
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedAllocate(unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::AlignedDeallocate(unsigned int)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::UnalignedDeallocate(unsigned int)'
```

How can I fix this error?
Is there something wrong with my code?

I am installing crypto++ using synaptic package manager for this package:

```
libcrypto++-utils
libcrypto++8
libcrypto++8-dbg
libcrypto++-dev
libcrypto++-doc
```

and libcrypto++.a and libcrypto++.so can be found in /usr/lib/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried use g++ to compile, but those error still there. what C++ code should i link? thanks.

Comment: i believe AlignedAllocate(unsigned int) used in crypto++/secblock.h that include crypto++/misc.h where AlignedAllocate(unsigned int) is declared, but somehow AlignedAllocate(unsigned int) implementation not found, and this error occured. what should i do?

Comment: i've tried to include crypto++/misc.h in my program, but those error still ocuured.

Comment: This implies a problem with how the libs are installed, could you update the question with the output of `gcc -o test test.cpp -lcrypto++ -Wl,-v` (I took `-L/usr/lib/crypto++` out of that command because if the libs are installed in `/usr/lib` then telling the linker to look in the non-existent dir `/usr/lib/crypto++` is a waste of time)

Comment: @jonathan: wow! it works! i change -L/usr/lib/crypto++ to -L/usr/lib/ and it works! you're right, i think the compiler look for the non-existent -L/usr/lib/crypto++ dir, after change it to -L/usr/lib/, the compiler look for the right dir thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command looks wrong:

```
gcc -o test test.cpp -L/usr/lib/crypto++ -lcrypto++
```

If (as you say) the libs are in `/usr/lib` then you shouldn't be saying `-L/usr/lib/crypto++`

I think the `libcrypto++8` package installs its libs in the `-L/usr/lib/crypto++` directory, and presumably they are incompatible and don't provide the undefined symbols your program needs.

You should compile with simply:

```
gcc -o test test.cpp -lcrypto++
```

(There's no need to say `-L/usr/lib` as it's the default location for libraries anyway)

Answer (score 7):

it solved!
i change my command from:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/lib/crypto++ -lcrypto++
```

to this command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lcryptopp -lpthread
```

i add -lpthread because after i used this command:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp -L/usr/lib/ -lcryptopp
```

i get these errors:

```
./libcryptopp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
./libcryptopp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
./libcryptopp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
./libcryptopp.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
```

i misunderstood about -L/usr/lib/crypto++ arg, i thought compiler will search for crypto++ in /usr/lib/ dir, it turned out the compiler will search for crypto++ in -L/usr/lib/crypto++ dir, whereas the package installed in -L/usr/lib/ dir.

thanks to @jonathan wakely.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too.
your compiler need to bind library files to your program , so because it cannot find any implementation of your decleration!

i still not solve my problem. but you have a way other!!!
you can instead `.cpp` original files with library files.

you can download `Cryptopp` originally from below link :

https://www.cryptopp.com/cryptopp563.zip